# Magento 2: Show Image by its Role

Tags: magento2, code

I want to create a custom image role and assign it to product. Only those products image will be shown on category page having that custom role.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

**Step-1:** Create **registration.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/CustomImageRole**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'VendoreName_CustomImageRole', __DIR__);
```

**Step-2:** Create **module.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/CustomImageRole/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendoreName_CustomImageRole" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step-3:** Now we create custom image role attributes. Create **InstallData.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/CustomImageRole/Setup**

```
<?php
 
namespace VendoreName\CustomImageRole\Setup;
 
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
 
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
 
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
 
        /* Image Type Banner Top */
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'top_banner_image');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'top_banner_image',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Top Banner',
                'input' => 'media_image',
                'frontend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Frontend\Image',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'filterable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'required' => false,
            ]
        );
 
        /* Image Type Banner Top Left */
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'top_banner_left_image');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'top_banner_left_image',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Top Banner Left',
                'input' => 'media_image',
                'frontend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Frontend\Image',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'filterable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'sort_order' => 110,
                'required' => false,
            ]
        );
    }
 
}
```

**Step-4:** Create **di.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/CustomImageRole/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="remove_custom_image_type" type="VendoreName\CustomImageRole\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product\RemoveImagesToGalleryBlock" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
 
</config>
```

**Step-5:** Create **RemoveImagesToGalleryBlock.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/CustomImageRole/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Product**

```
<?php
 
namespace VendoreName\CustomImageRole\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product;
 
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
 
class RemoveImagesToGalleryBlock
{
    protected $_filesystem;
    protected $_collectionFactory;
 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
    ) {
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }
 
    public function afterGetMediaGalleryImages(Product $subject, $result)
    {
        $directory = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        if ($subject->hasData('media_gallery_images')) {
            $subject->setData('media_gallery_images', $this->_collectionFactory->create());
            if (!$subject->getData('media_gallery_images')->count() && is_array($subject->getMediaGallery('images'))) {
                $images = $subject->getData('media_gallery_images');
                foreach ($subject->getMediaGallery('images') as $image) {
                    if (!empty($image['disabled'])
                        || !empty($image['removed'])
                        || empty($image['value_id'])
                        || $images->getItemById($image['value_id']) != null
                    ) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    // check top banner left image
                    if ($image['file'] == $subject->getTopBannerLeftImage()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    // check top banner image
                    if ($image['file'] == $subject->getTopBannerImage()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $image['url'] = $subject->getMediaConfig()->getMediaUrl($image['file']);
                    $image['id'] = $image['value_id'];
                    $image['path'] = $directory->getAbsolutePath($subject->getMediaConfig()->getMediaPath($image['file']));
                    $images->addItem(new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($image));
 
                }
                $subject->setData('media_gallery_images', $images);
            }
        }
        return $subject->getData('media_gallery_images');
    }
}
```

**Step-6:** Create **catalog_product_view.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/CustomImageRole/view/frontend/layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <container name="custom.page.top.wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom_page_top_wrapper" after="header.container">
                <container name="custom.page.top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom_page_top">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.topimage" template="VendoreName_CustomImageRole::product/view/product-topimage.phtml" before="-"/>
                </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="custom.page.top"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step-7:** Create **product-topimage.phtml** at **app/code/VendoreName/CustomImageRole/view/frontend/templates/product/view**

```
<?php
$customizeHelper = $this->helper(\VendoreName\CustomImageRole\Helper\Data::class);
$productData = $customizeHelper->getCurrentProduct();
$allowed = array('gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');
if ($productData) {
    /* Top Banner Image */
    if ($productData->getTopBannerImage()) {
        $filename = $productData->getTopBannerImage();
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
            $topUrl = $customizeHelper->getTopBannerImageUrl($productData->getTopBannerImage());
            ?>
            <div class="top_bg_image" style="background : #FFF url('<?= $block->escapeUrl($topUrl) ?>') no-repeat center;"
                 alt="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($productData->getTopBannerImage()) ?>"> </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
 
    /* Top Banner Image Left */
    if ($productData->getTopBannerLeftImage()) {
        $filename = $productData->getTopBannerLeftImage();
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
            $topLeftUrl = $customizeHelper->getTopBannerImageUrl($productData->getTopBannerLeftImage());
            ?>
            <div class="product_left_image">
                <img src='<?= $block->escapeUrl($topLeftUrl) ?>' alt="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($productData->getTopBannerLeftImage()) ?>" >
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
<style>
.custom_page_top {display: block;width: 100%;}
.top_bg_image {min-height: 300px;width: 50%;float: right;}
.product_left_image {display: block;float: left;width: 50%;}
</style>
```

**Step-8:** Create **Data.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/CustomImageRole/Helper**

```
<?php
 
namespace VendoreName\CustomImageRole\Helper;
 
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
 
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $registry;
 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
 
    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    }
 
    public function getTopBannerImageUrl($imageName)
    {
        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
        return $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $imageName;
    }
}
```

> **After creating and adding above file run Magento 2 commands**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

[Click Here for More](https://dolphinwebsolution.com/how-to-add-custom-product-image-role-in-magento-2/)